# How can i know which printer connect to cash drawer.(EPSON SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, epson

I am using ePOS2 SDK from Epson to communicate with receipt printer TM-M30.
I am able to successfully connect to printer and print some data.but i need to open cash drawer. so currently i does not know in which printer cash drawer is connected.so currently i added for loop and check all the printer.pls check my code

```
NSMutableArray *SelectedPrinter=[[NSUSERDEFAULTS valueForKey:@"SelectedPrinter"] mutableCopy];
        for (int i=0; i<SelectedPrinter.count; i++)
        {
            [self printdataWithTarget:[[SelectedPrinter objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"modelName"] withDeviceName:[[SelectedPrinter objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"portName"]];
        }

-(void)printdataWithTarget:(NSString*)target withDeviceName:(NSString *)deviceName
{
    [[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] disconnectPrinter];
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        [[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] disconnectPrinter];
        if ([[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] initializePrinter:deviceName])
        {
            if (![[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] connectPrinterWithPort:target])
            {
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[APPDELEGATE window] animated:YES];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[APPDELEGATE window] animated:YES];
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
                });
                //showAlert(@"",@"Please ensure your device is connected with the Printer and you have selected this hardware from the settings menu.");
            }
            else
            {
                if ([[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] isPrintable:[[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] getStatus]])
                {
                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] addTextAlign:1];
                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] addText:@""];
                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] forceStopSound:0];

                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] setReceiveEventDelegate:self];
                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] addPulse:EPOS2_DRAWER_HIGH time:EPOS2_PULSE_100];
                    [[[MPOSPrinter sharedManager] printer] sendData:EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT];

                }
                else{
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[APPDELEGATE window] animated:YES];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[APPDELEGATE window] animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"Not Initialize");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you "getStatus" and then check if the drawer is in the "unknown" state.  If it is connected it ought to report "open" or "closed".

See [getStatus documentation](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_ios_en/index.php?content_id=114).